# Reactjs - Export to Excel using xlsx.utils.json_to_sheet

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using xlsx npm package to export data to excel. The following code is working as expected and data is exported. I need to apply some style as below. Please help.

1. Header should be bold.
2. Header background should be gray
3. Apply border

**Import statement**

```
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
```

**Code:**

```
var data = [
  {"name":"John", "city": "Seattle"},
  {"name":"Mike", "city": "Los Angeles"},
  {"name":"Zach", "city": "New York"}
];
let header = ["Name", "City"];
const ws = XLSX.utils.book_new();
XLSX.utils.sheet_add_aoa(ws, [header]);
XLSX.utils.sheet_add_json(ws, data, { origin: 'A2', skipHeader: true });
const wb = { Sheets: { 'data': ws }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
const excelBuffer = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: fileType, type: 'array', cellStyles:true });
const finalData = new Blob([excelBuffer], { type: fileFormat });
FileSaver.saveAs(finalData, "Data.xlsx");
```

**Actual Output:**

[image]

**Expected Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do this with `xlsx` aka `SheetJS` because it is probably a `SheetJS Pro` feature.

You can do it with [xlsx-populate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx-populate).

Demo at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-goldwasser-888e9?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: I tried doing it with xlsx-populate and I could not build.  Is there a problem with using this package in react application?

Comment: Thank you this CodeSandbox is fantastic.

Comment: It is supported in Typescript?
I am trying to integrate in react + TypeScript, working fine but need to pass any.
Main concern in sheetData type, we are getting sheetData as string[][] but 
cell value expect only string | number | boolean  not an Array value.