# how to export data to excel in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, excel

I have some data from a REST API server and I want to export them into an excel file. I saw in another question that it can be done using [react-export-excel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-export-excel). but when I tried it like the [example code](https://github.com/rdcalle/react-export-excel/blob/HEAD/examples/simple_excel_export_01.md), it gives this error even though I already included the jszip dependencies (3.10.0):

```
Could not find module in path: 'jszip/2.4.0' relative to '/node_modules/xlsx/xlsx.js'
```

if I changed the jszip into the 2.4.0 version, it gives this error instead:

```
Could not find module in path: 'jszip' relative to '/node_modules/xlsx/xlsx.js'
```

here's my code (and here's the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-sammet-2wvusp?file=/src/App.js))

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";
import ReactExport from "react-export-excel";

const ExcelFile = ReactExport.ExcelFile;
const ExcelSheet = ReactExport.ExcelFile.ExcelSheet;
const ExcelColumn = ReactExport.ExcelFile.ExcelColumn;

const dataSet1 = [
  {
    name: "Johson",
    amount: 30000,
    sex: "M",
    is_married: true
  },
  {
    name: "Monika",
    amount: 355000,
    sex: "F",
    is_married: false
  },
  {
    name: "John",
    amount: 250000,
    sex: "M",
    is_married: false
  },
  {
    name: "Josef",
    amount: 450500,
    sex: "M",
    is_married: true
  }
];

const dataSet2 = [
  {
    name: "Johnson",
    total: 25,
    remainig: 16
  },
  {
    name: "Josef",
    total: 25,
    remainig: 7
  }
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: consider this post 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66853322/reactjs-export-to-excel-using-xlsx-utils-json-to-sheet

Comment: @Shachar297 after I started using `xlsx-populate`, my app crashed with an error `can't resolve 'crypto'...`. I tried all the solutions given in other questions about this but none of them works.